# Directive does not work properly on input field

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which allows user to input alphabet and numeric only as the following:

```
app.register.directive('alphaNumericOnlyWithMaximum6Characters', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
            modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(inputValue) {
                if (inputValue == undefined) return '';
                var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/g, '');
                if (transformedInput != inputValue) {
                    modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                    modelCtrl.$render();
                } else if (inputValue.length > 6) {
                    transformedInput = inputValue.substring(0, 6);
                    modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                    modelCtrl.$render();
                }
                scope.securityToken = transformedInput;
                return;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

View:

`<input type="text" ng-class="{tokenError: tokenError}" alpha-numeric-only-with-maximum6-characters id="inputToken" name="securityToken" ng-model="securityToken" required autofocus>`

I need to update securityToken on my controller. For example: the token number is 123456.

> When I enter 1. The token is undefined.
>  Enter 2. The token is
>   12.
>  Enter 3. the token is undefined. 
>   Enter 4, the token is 1234. 
>   Enter 5, the token is undefined. 
>   Enter 6, the token is 123456.

I don't know why sometimes the directive is not working. Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: could you add the input element where you have used directive..that might have `ng-maxlength` directive..

Comment: Just update it. Thank you! there is no ng-maxlength on input element.